# Split Dataframe with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Goal:**

I would like to split my dataframe into 3 multiple dataframes.
My problem is, I don't know how I can get the dataframes with the more similar sum of "value" column for each one

**Here is my current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import math

splitter = 3

df = pd.read_csv('account.csv')
q_rows = df.shape[0]                                # Number of rows
q_rows_x_dataframe = math.ceil(q_rows / splitter)   # Quantity of rows for splitter

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row.shift(q_rows_x_dataframe + 1)

>>> df
   network  value
0        A   1400
1        B   1300
2        C   1200
3        D   1100
4        E   1000
5        F    900
6        G    800
7        H    700
8        I    600
9        J    500
10       K    400
11       L    300
12       M    200
13       N    100
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
A   1400
D   1100
G   800
J   500
M   200


B   1300
E   1000
H   700
K   400
N   100


C   1200
F   900
I   600
L   300
```

Comment: `[d for k,d in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//splittter)]`

Comment: Please, check the "what I'm looking for". Your code don't do exactly that! Thanks @QuangHoang

Comment: It DOES give you **multiple dataframes**. How would you want to store those dataframes?

Comment: I need 3 dataframes not 5.  I would have the most equal sum of "value" in each one! Sorry my english is not good. @QuangHoang

Comment: My apology, this should work `[d for k,d in df.groupby(np.tile(np.arange(splitter), len(df))[:len(df)])]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group with a modulus on the index should work:

```
splitter = 3
[g for _, g in df.groupby(df.index % splitter)]

[   network  value
 0        A   1400
 3        D   1100
 6        G    800
 9        J    500
 12       M    200,    network  value
 1        B   1300
 4        E   1000
 7        H    700
 10       K    400
 13       N    100,    network  value
 2        C   1200
 5        F    900
 8        I    600
 11       L    300]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
splitter = 3
dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.index % splitter)))
```

Output:

```
{0:    network  value
 0        A   1400
 3        D   1100
 6        G    800
 9        J    500
 12       M    200, 1:    network  value
 1        B   1300
 4        E   1000
 7        H    700
 10       K    400
 13       N    100, 2:    network  value
 2        C   1200
 5        F    900
 8        I    600
 11       L    300}
```